# How to Handle Orientation in IOS Objective C only for one screen and reset when press

Tags: ios, objective-c, orientation, back, landscape

I'm new to the IOS development and I have to give landscape and Portrait only for one screen and all others should be portrait only. I use following code in AppDelegate file and  change it in my screen. But when I press back button previous screen not rotate to Portrait again?

```
- (UIInterfaceOrientationMask)application:(UIApplication *) application
  supportedInterfaceOrientationsForWindow:(UIWindow *) window {
    if (self.allowLandscape) {
        return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskLandscapeLeft &
        UIInterfaceOrientationMaskLandscapeRight;
    }
    return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskPortrait;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add below code inside viewWillAppear on all viewControllers you want to show portrait only. don't forget to mark Device Orientation to both Portrait and Landscape modes.

```
NSNumber *value = [NSNumber numberWithInt:UIDeviceOrientationPortrait];
[[UIDevice currentDevice] setValue:value forKey:@"orientation"];
```